# Running acts-as-taggable-on in engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, acts-as-taggable-on

I'm trying to add acts-as-taggable-on gem as dependency into my mountable engine (which then is loaded into other application like gem).

Following the steps and adding it into engine.gemspec then running `bundle install` is fetching gem successfully, but when I try to execute `rake acts_as_taggable_on_engine:install:migrations` task, from engine or the app I receive the following message :

> Don't know how to build task
>   'acts_as_taggable_on_engine:install:migrations'

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Add "require 'acts-as-taggable-on'" to your engine file:

```
module YourEngine
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    require 'acts-as-taggable-on'
    ...
  end
end
```

Then to see the rake tasks using "rake -T".

In my engine I am using "rake app:acts_as_taggable_on_engine:install:migrations". However, this will copy all migrations to my dummy app. What I did is manually moving that migrations from my dummy app to my engine, then run rake db:migrate.